# Python: How to create a dictionary that contains some functions, without running them on assignment?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have the following dictionary containing a bunch of functions and their keys as in the bellow example:

```
function_list = {0:power_off(), 1:image_capture(100,1000,100,100), 2:video_record(100,100), 3:image_settings(), 4:video_settings(), 5:device_settings()}
```

Actually there are about 5 times more, but I simplified it for this post...
My question is, how should I proceed so that when I define the **function_list** dictionary, it will not run all the functions from it's content, rather just at when I call them in the following manner: **function_list[current_selection]**, based on the value of **current_selection** parameter.

I'm doing this so I don't have to have a long and complex if... elif statement like:

```
if current_selection == 0:
    power_off()
elif current_selection == 1:
    image_capture(100,1000,100,100)
elif current_selection ==2:
    video_record(100,100)
... and so on ...
```

If anyone could help me out, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
function_list = {0:{"func":power_off},
                 1:{"func":image_capture, "args":(100,1000,100,100)},
                 2:{"func":video_record, "args":(100,100)},
                 3:{"func":image_settings},
                 4:{"func":video_settings},
                 5:{"func":device_settings} }

f = function_list[current_selection]
if "args" in f:
    f["func"](*f["args"])
else:
    f["func"]()
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this should work.
Testing it right away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are making function calls. The values in the dictionary should be function references.

`function_list = {0:power_off}`
and then to call, 
`function_list[0]()`.

If you have to pass arguments, you can replace the function reference with a lambda expression.

`function_list = {1: lambda arg1, arg2: image_capture(arg1, arg2)}`

Comment: [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is a slightly easier way of doing this than a lambda.